# how to select specific values of an element in python3

Tags: python-3.x, css-selectors, distinct-values

This is my first question so it may be quite basic.
I've managed to id and select the element but I cannot extract especific values like "IDinmobiliarias" from it.

```
data = soup.select('#PropJSON')
print(data)
```

When I do this, I get this output:

```
[<input id="PropJSON" type="hidden" value='{"id":"186226916","IDinmobiliarias":"108","IDoperaciones":"1","tipoPropiedad":"2","IDdepartamentos":"10","IDzonas":"13","IDpais":"1","refered":1,"particular":"0","temporario":0,"proyecto":0,"destaque":1,"IDmoneda":"1","monto":"1595000","precio_en_usd":1595000,"monedaISO":"USD"}'/>]
```

How can I extract the "108" for example?
I've tried different things without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select will return to you a list. You can then iterate over that list and get the data of the value attribute by accessing it like a dictionary. Once you have the data you will need to parse it with json then you can select any element you like from it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = """<input id="PropJSON" type="hidden" value='{"id":"186226916","IDinmobiliarias":"108","IDoperaciones":"1","tipoPropiedad":"2","IDdepartamentos":"10","IDzonas":"13","IDpais":"1","refered":1,"particular":"0","temporario":0,"proyecto":0,"destaque":1,"IDmoneda":"1","monto":"1595000","precio_en_usd":1595000,"monedaISO":"USD"}'/>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
data = soup.select('#PropJSON')
for input_tag in data:
    json_string = json.loads(input_tag['value'])
    print(json_string['IDinmobiliarias'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
108
```